# Is there a way the robot go through goal point without stopping?

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to limit the travel path of the robot to some extent.
So, I set goal minutely and published the goals to move_base using SimpleActionServer.

This plan was successful that the robot go through the route I envisioned, but the robot stopped at each goal points.

Is there a way the robot go through goal point without stopping?

I've found that teb_local_plannner has a parameter called free_goal_vel, which seems to be close to what I want.
But I don't want to use teb_local_plannner, because teb_local_plannner seems to retreat frequently.
Now I use base_local_planner.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361577/is-there-a-way-the-robot-go-through-goal-point-without-stopping?/) by [ayato](https://answers.ros.org/users/57482/ayato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There isn't a super clean way to do this - but you can approximate this behavior. Have the node that is sending goals to move_base monitor the progress and when you get "close" to your previously sent goal, send the next goal. The new goal will supersede the old one seamlessly. You can determine the robot's position either through TF or by monitoring the feedback topic of the move_base action.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayato](https://answers.ros.org/users/57482/ayato/) on 2020-09-22**:
Thank you @fergs.
I will try to implement node the way you taught me.

**Comment by [Thazz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39841/thazz/) on 2020-09-23**:
This kind of logic is implemented in [yocs_waypoints_navi](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_waypoints_navi) package so you can take a look there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another way to do this is using [move_base_flex](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_flex) package. There you have GetPath action which returns path generated by global planner between 2 points.

Then you can iterate through all your goal points and get path between each 2 points. At the end you concatenate all these partial paths into single final path from first to last waypoint and call local planner on this path.

---

Originally posted by [Thazz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39841/thazz/) with karma: 66 on 2020-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1